# Merging similar tables in SQL part 2

Tags: php, mysql, merge, left-join, union-all

I think people were reluctant to help me last time because I didn't want to post up the columns, but I'm eager to solve this, so I'm putting aside my better judgement and laying it bare.

OK, I have two similar tables, and I'm using MySQL, and PHP to generate the tables.  So far I have 3 tables:

```
CPE:
fastethernet00,subnet00,fastethernet01,subnet01,hsrp,vip,bgp,bgp_neighbor,remote_as,bgp_customer_net,next_hop,loopback,cpe,hostname,cpe_cust_index,int_next_hop_1,int_next_hop_2,voice,solution

Liverpool:
apn1,apn2,apn3,apn4,apn5,customer,vpi_vci,vlan1,cust_index,RADIUS,nexthop,atinterface1,atinterface2,feinterface1,feinterface2,spinterface1,spinterface2,ip_address_range1,ip_address_range2,handset_address_range1,handset_address_range2,handset_address_range3,handset_address_range4,handset_address_range5,handset_address_range6,handset_address_range7,handset_address_range8,handset_address_range9,handset_address_range10,handset_address_range11,handset_address_range12,handset_address_range13,handset_address_range14,handset_address_range15,handset_address_range16,DNS_Server1,DNS_Server2,OLVDMVPN,live

Greenwich:
apn_1,apn_2,apn_3,apn_4,apn_5,customer_,vpi_vci_,vlan_1,cust_index_,RADIUS_,nexthop_,atinterface_1,atinterface_2,feinterface_1,feinterface_2,spinterface_1,spinterface_2,ip_address_range_1,ip_address_range_2,handset_address_range_1,handset_address_range_2,handset_address_range_3,handset_address_range_4,handset_address_range_5,handset_address_range_6,handset_address_range_7,handset_address_range_8,handset_address_range_9,handset_address_range_10,handset_address_range_11,handset_address_range_12,handset_address_range_13,handset_address_range_14,handset_address_range_15,handset_address_range_16,DNS_Server_1,DNS_Server_2,OLVDMVPN_,live_
```

The first step I need to accomplish is linking Greenwich to Liverpool via apn_1/apn1.  The same record won't necessarily be on both, and there may even be duplicates.  The php I'm using to create this table is throwing up a syntax error around the UNION ALL:

```
mysql_query ("CREATE TABLE Both (
SELECT * FROM `Greenwich` left outer join Liverpool on Greenwich.apn_1 = Liverpool.apn1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Greenwich
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Liverpool on Greenwich.apn_1 = Liverpool.apn1  where Greenwich.apn_1 is null)")
```

Can anyone see what's wrong with that?

Afterwards, I need to then link the resultant table to cpe_cust_index via cust_index/cust_index_, so ideally I think I need to merge these cells.  If these cells are present in Greenwich and Liverpool they will always be the same.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Soop: Why do you have "where Greenwich.apn_1 is null" included in your second subquery?

Comment: It should include all entries from Greenwich and Liverpool - all the ones from liverpool and Greenwich that match, and then all the ones on Liverpool that aren't on greenwich

Comment: individual tables for towns/cities - hmmmm, not a good start.

Comment: It's not towns and cities, it's 2 seperate servers.

Comment: @Soop: If Greenwich.apn_1 is never null then you will definitely have a UNION error I think...

Comment: hmm.  I don't understand...  even if I remove that last part, it still errors.

Comment: Did you try running the query with all the columns explicitly specified?

Comment: Also, merely from a suspicion that on some stage some buggy parser might parse this SQL script, I would try enclosing the two subselects in parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the 3rd way described here, using a "mutex (mutually exclusive) table

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/

This plus a filter give me exactly what I need.  Now I just have to merge the index fields together, and apn 1 fields together.

Answer (score 0):

Try naming all the columns that you want to select and alias then using `AS` so that they match. `Union` does not like column name mismatches.

Eg.

```
Select col1 as col1, col2 as col2 from table1
Union
Select col-1 as col1, col-2 as col2 from table2
```

Comment: I can't see how there will be a mismatch, Adrian. @Soop is selecting * (ALL) from the same table: Greenwich!